# Running excel macro for excel books that does not contain that macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a macro that is not present in my excel document, it is recorded in another excel doc or in another file if it is possible.

I have tried to open two excel books, first that contains that macro and the second one that does not contain and when I run that macro it says that my excel book does not contain that macro.

```
Option Explicit
Dim x1App, x1Book, x2App, x2Book
dim fso
dim curDir
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing

Set x1App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x2App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set x1Book = x1App.Workbooks.Open(curDir & "\test.xlsm", 0, true)
Set x2Book = x2App.Workbooks.Open(curDir & "\perf.csv", 0, true)
x1App.visible = true
x2App.visible = true
x1App.Run "MyMacro"
x2App.Run "MyMacro"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
```

So here my macro is in test.xlsm excel file and i want to run it on perf.csv.

In this way I can't do it. Is there any other way to do this kind of staff?

I have also exported the macro to the file than copied the content of the macro to my *.vbs script to run it directly from their and also no success.

Comment: try to open both workbook in one application, not two as you do now. Assuming that your macro run for activeworkbook then the other logic should be ok.

Comment: one more thing- you would need to call macro name including workbook name where it is placed in this way: `x1App.Run "test.xlsm!MyMacro"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example of the code

```
Option Explicit

Dim x1App, x1Book, x2App, x2Book
dim fso
dim curDir
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing

Set x1App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x1Book = x1App.Workbooks.Open(curDir & "\macro_for_creating_charts")
Set x2Book = x1App.Workbooks.Open(curDir & "\agent_perf.csv")
'x1App.visible = true
x1App.Run "macro_for_creating_charts.xlsm!Macro4"
x1App.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)
x1App.Quit
```